# What's the safest way to attach support wires to posts for long runs of string lights?

Tags: patio, pergola

A very crude drawing of my patio/pool is below. I want to light the place up with LED string lights, but I am wary of damaging the pergola posts. Specifically for the cables that would cross the pool.

The posts are 8x8 lumber and the 24' beams extend across the pool. My primary concern is how to attach the cables to the corner posts. Should there be a separate eyebolt for each run of cable? If the diagonal runs connect to eyebolts on the flat side of a post, does it risk splitting the lumber?

Would it be better to attach the cable to some sort of steel band ([like this](https://a.co/d/hnJCDfH)) around around the posts?

I'd appreciate any advice.

Here's [a better look at the pergola](https://www.icloud.com/photos/#0ddgO1HV3WVDJ0PZmIPSr7HkQ) if it helps...

[image: Patio/pool rough layout]

Comment: Look up the electric code rules for wires over a pool. I recall something about high clearance rules there because of the common use of long aluminum poles (skimmer net, pool vac) in the vicinity of a pool.

Answer (score 1):

It does exert a splitting force, but not a very big force. (dependng somewhat on how tight the cateneries are)

If it worries you install the eye bolts at an intermediate angle between the two strand directions, or reinforce the posts with a metal band.

Check the local regulations for electricity around swimming pools,

Comment: After posting the question, I found this product on Amazon. Is this the kind of metal band you meant or did you mean a more custom build? https://a.co/d/hnJCDfH

Comment: I was thinking something more mundane like nail-on strapping. https://strongtie.co.nz/products/cs-coiled-strap

Answer (score 0):

Installing two lines to one eyebolt on the face shown in your drawing doesn't offend me. With a sagging wire and the horizontal side pull, though, I would settle for orienting the plane of the eye parallel to the ground. The sag's side pull would annoy me every time *I* looked at it, but that's a personal problem of mine.

Lag type 1/4" or even 5/16" eyebolts don't risk splitting an 8" post even if there's no pilot hole (unless your anchorage is within, say, 3" of the post's top). Without a pilot hole the risk is of shearing off the eyebolt before you get it anchored to full depth. Use a pilot hole and feel free to lubricate the threads with soap or wax. A bit of side load poses no splitting risk either, but you can install a couple bolts through the post perpendicular to the hypothetical split if the idea of splitting will disturb your sleep.

I would prefer bolting through to a nut on the other side since there's electrical involved. I suspect you would need a 1/2" eyebolt (with shoulder) to get one sufficiently long for that 8" grip. Consider [eye nuts](https://e-rigging.com/products/stainless-eye-nuts?variant=39745720189001) so that you can buy skinnier-than-1/2" threaded rods for the 8" grip:

[image: eye nut]

You never can see the thread engagement with eye nuts, so you would never know if the threaded rod was backing out. Use threadlocker in the rod to eye nut connection if you use eye nuts.

You might also try to drill your holes at a slight downward angle to match the sag at the ends. This would avoid that personal problem of mine. Too steep would look *terrible*, so you might ignore that advice to avoid a personal problem of your own.

Comment: Would these steel "post bands" be a better or worse idea than eye bolts through the post?
https://a.co/d/hnJCDfH

Comment: I can't speak to the strength of them, but one of the "attachments" they sell is a shackle they suggest for anchoring a hammock. https://a.co/d/bENzDTr

Comment: @JCFord, beside a pool, I would impose stainless steel as a constraint. Hot dip galvanization at the bare minimum.

Comment: These are hot dip galvanized and then powder coated according to the product listing.

You've given me a lot to go on. Thanks.

Comment: @JCFord, I typically try to avoid mixing metals for little projects like this unless the two metals are aluminum and zinc. You might check out the table at the bottom of https://galvanizeit.org/knowledgebase/article/stainless-steel-in-contact-with-galvanized-steel if you're combining dissimilar metals. I never have trusted hot dip galvanized wire rope for corrosion resistance, so I would use stainless wire rope in your application. HDG 9 gauge wire would work, but it wouldn't sag as smoothly.